# Is angular 1.x still relatable

Tags: angularjs, angular

Have a few projects in angular 1.x and wondering if its really necessary/efficient to move them to angular 4 / later.

Smaller dashboards would not be necessary as it is used internally by minimum number of people. But the bigger customer facing application (3 year old product ) is under the question, as new requirements are being developed.

According to surveys, Angular 1.x is still being used in many companies and the community is still active on making new libraries.

So is it worth shifting?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should leave those projects in Angular 1 and start using Angular 7 for newer Projects. Here is a good article comparing the two: https://www.uruit.com/blog/angular-1-vs-2-migrate/

Answer (score 0):

If you have projects on angular1 developed, then those can be migrated to angular 7 module by module.

Means Using Current angular version, you can run your project in hybrid mode, where you can run angular 7 and angular 1 code together.

For clear understanding, please read these below links
1) https://angular.io/guide/upgrade
2) https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/angularjs-to-angular5-upgrading-a-large-application-7e6fbf70bafa

Comment: Thanks for the advise and the material to look further.